# Try to logon into RDOPstStore using 20 gb of .pst file

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

I am writing a code in C# to logon into "personal storage table" file which is of "20 gigabyte" , I am getting an ERROR as `I_Message_Service_Admin :: Configure_Message_Service: MAP_I_E_EXTENDED_ERROR`.

Can anyone help me in it?

Comment: An error specific to a message service. To get the `MAPIERROR`````````` structure that describes the error, the client application should call the `IMsgServiceAdmin::GetLastError` method.

Comment: If you run the PST file through scanpst.exe, does it find any errors? Can the PST file be opened in Outlook?